# How to separate data types from a text file?

Tags: java

This is the code I have Implemented but I am getting multiple arrays of data in a incremental order but I need single arrays of data. How do I approach that ? Also is it ok to have try catch inside catch block ?

```
  Text File:
  The 1493 fox 0.4 -6.382 jumped -832722 0 1 9E-21 162 over the dog!
```

Eg: Double values are printed each time data is added to it.

```
   @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner s= new Scanner(new File("src/inputs.txt")).useDelimiter("\\s+");

    ArrayList<Long> itr= new ArrayList<Long>();
    ArrayList<Double> dub = new ArrayList<Double>();
    ArrayList<String> str = new ArrayList<String>();

    while(s.hasNext())
    {
        String str1=s.next();
    try
        {   
        long b=Long.parseLong(str1);
        itr.add(b);
        System.out.println("Integer values are ::"+itr);    
        }
    catch(NumberFormatException e)
     {
      try
        {   
        double b1=Double.parseDouble(str1);
        dub.add(b1);
        System.out.println("Double values are ::"+dub); 
        }
       catch(NumberFormatException e1)
        {
           String b2 = (String) str1;
           str.add(b2);
           System.out.println("String Values are"+str);
        }
     }
   }
 }}
```

Expected output :

```
  Integer values are ::[1493, -832722, 0, 1]
  Double values are ::[0.4, -6.382, 9.0E-21]
  String Values are[The, fox, jumped, over, the, dog!]
```

Comment: @Bohemian Updated.....

Comment: Print the Arraylist outside of while loop.

Comment: I agree with @pikrut. Move the three println outside the while, at the end of the algorithm. Also, why are you using Long instead of Integer for the first type?

Comment: @don I don't understand what you're asking. to get an idea of what you want, I would have to examine your code and visually debug it, and I'm not going to do that. You need to narrow your question to the sharpest thing you can, and reduce your code likewise, to perhaps just a couple of lines.

Comment: @RubioRic  assignment Question did what they asked.

Comment: @Bohemian OP has removed the explanation trying to accomplish your requirements. He is reading tokens from a file and determing their type. He is not obtaining his desired output because he is printing in each iteration instead of printing once there is no more to read and the loop has finished. Also he is asking if there is a better way to determine tokens' type.

Comment: @bohemian I have updated it few minutes back. Code cannot be reduced any further. At one place in node.js guys keep asking me to put more information, here your are asking me to reduce it(code). Requesting you to take it off from hold. Even though I might have got the required info from users above. Still there might be some other guys who might give some useful info.

Comment: @Rubio I hear you. Go ahead and answer it then.

Comment: @Bohemian Thanks. I got no better way and I have already pointed the main problem.

Comment: @donop Include your input for clarification purposes.

Comment: @don op: If you want answers that are more friendly, use an IDE that automatically indents your code. Currently it looks quite chaotic, which makes it harder to read. Properly indented code just gives a better impression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @RubioRic answered, move the SOP statements outside the while loop to get the desired output.

As to other ways to get the data types, I feel your implementation is good enough and widely used. But if you want to do it in an another way then try using regex patterns to validate the string and determine the data type **(not reliable)** OR use the Scanner class API to determine the data type like below.

```
 @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner s= new Scanner(new File("src/inputs.txt")).useDelimiter("\\s+");

        ArrayList<Long> itr= new ArrayList<Long>();
        ArrayList<Double> dub = new ArrayList<Double>();
        ArrayList<String> str = new ArrayList<String>();

        while(s.hasNext())
        {
            if(s.hasNextLong()){
                 itr.add(s.nextLong());
            }
            else if(s.hasNextDouble()){
                 dub.add(s.nextDouble());
            }
            else{
                 str.add(s.next());
             }  
        }
        s.close();
 System.out.println("Long values are ::" + itr);
 System.out.println("Double values are ::" + dub);     
 System.out.println("String Values are" + str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just move the printing outside the loop. Got no better solution without using try-catch, sorry.

```
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
Scanner s= new Scanner(new File("src/inputs.txt")).useDelimiter("\\s+");

ArrayList<Long> itr   = new ArrayList<Long>();
ArrayList<Double> dub = new ArrayList<Double>();
ArrayList<String> str = new ArrayList<String>();

while(s.hasNext()) {
    String str1=s.next();

    try {   
        long b=Long.parseLong(str1);
        itr.add(b);

    } catch(NumberFormatException e) {

      try {   
         double b1=Double.parseDouble(str1);
         dub.add(b1);
      } catch(NumberFormatException e1) {
        String b2 = (String) str1;
        str.add(b2);
      }
    }
 }

 System.out.println("Integer values are ::" + itr);
 System.out.println("Double values are ::" + dub);     
 System.out.println("String Values are" + str);
```